# Is below code correct to retain field1_1 value after selecting form drop down list and clicking on submit

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu, isset

I am using select tag to select any value(field1_1) form dropdown list and clicking on submit, however I am not able to retain the value(field1_1) which I had selected from dropdown, instead the 1st value from dropdown is popping up.

Could you please correct if anything is wrong?

I have used isset function in php

```
<?php if((isset($_POST['field1_1']) == $_POST['field1_1'])){echo $field1_1 = 'field1_1';}?>
```

below is the code:

```
<select name = "field1_1" value = "<?php if((isset($_POST['field1_1']) == 
$_POST['field1_1'])){echo $field1_1 = 'field1_1';}?>">
```

I want the latest selected value(field1_1) to be in the text box of the dropdown list

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: Why are you using `$_POST` inside `select` tag and you have missed the `option` tag

Comment: Hi, i am using below code


<select id = "release" name = "release" value=" ">
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('./pvt_dashboard.db');
$db->busyTimeout(1000);
if(!$db){
 echo "Fail";
 }
$result = $db->query("SELECT INTERFACE_ID_1 AS COUNT , INTERFACE_ID_1 FROM PVT_TABLE1 GROUP BY INTERFACE_ID_1 ORDER BY COUNT ASC");
while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
echo "<option value = \"".$row['INTERFACE_ID_1']."\">".$row['INTERFACE_ID_1']."</option>";
}
$db->close();
unset($db);
?>
</select>


which value should i use in select tag?